# Create a Validation Rule for an input field

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I want to create a Validation Rule where an user cannot enter Last Name as **Test** or **test**, it should throw an error stating, `Test contact cannot be created.` whenever an user enters last name as ***Test*** or ***test***.

I tried using AND condition and OR condition.

Here's my validation rule,

`AND(LastName <> "Test",LastName <> "test")`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, Validation rules return true when you want an error to occur

```
UPPER(LastName) = 'TEST'
```

is what you want, this covers, TEST, test, test, TeST, etc

Comment: @PrinceSharma cropredy's answer is correct given the information you've currently provided us. `LastName` is usually a field on `Lead` or `Contact`, not `Account` (unless you're perhaps using person accounts). This is starting to sound like there's extra information that you should include in your question.

Comment: @cropredy it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Cropredy's approach is the one I'd take, but if we wanted to stay close to your original attempt, what changes would we need to make (and why do they work)?

Re-wording the first bit of cropredy's answer, validation rules prevent the update of a record when the validation formula evaluates to `true`.

`AND(LastName <> "Test", LastName <> "test")` doesn't work here because if the `LastName` is either "Test" or "test", the result of that formula is false. This formula here is the exact opposite of what you want (it would only allow a LastName of "Test" or "test").

Thankfully, being the exact opposite means it's really simple to fix.

You could just wrap the entire thing in a `NOT()`, but that's the type of thing that would make me think the person writing it is not very skilled. The resulting formula can easily be simplified.

NOT causes `AND` to become `OR`, and `<>` to become `=`. The simplified validation formula would be `OR(LastName = "Test", LastName = "test")`